# How to fetch different user's unique id and unique child node and show it to recycelrview using FirebaseRecyclerOptions?

Tags: java

[Here is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCoFh.png)

here's my code:

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ClassData> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ClassData>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("Class"), ClassData.class)
                    .build();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager
            (2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    adapter = new subjectAdapterStudent(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```